# Manual approval in SaltStack formula

Tags: devops, salt-stack

I'm runnig specific script using salt and based on the log output of this script I need to choose whether to proceed with other tasks in salt formula.Is there any possibility to ask for user approval in salt formula. Basically I need something like this code snippet in bash:

```
echo "Proceed with copying users?(yes|no)"
read reply
if [ $reply == 'no' ]
then
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [provide input using `stdin`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run),

> stdin (str) -- A string of standard input can be specified for the
>   command to be run using the stdin parameter. This can be useful in
>   cases where sensitive information must be read from standard input.

you can also just echo the input into a script,

```
echo "some value" | script
```

Comment: So actually I'm asking how to interactively input some value to a script during salt formula run.